# Java: Confused on ant and exec

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, build

From the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) doc:

> executable    the command to execute without any command line arguments.

But in the example it shows:

```
<exec dir="${src}" executable="cmd.exe" os="Windows 2000" output="dir.txt">  
  <arg line="/c dir"/>  
</exec>
```

Isn't this contradictory?
Since if I understand the example the `/c dir` is a command line argument to `cmd.exe` but as an `executable` it is not supposed to have command line arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the ***executable* attribute** should not contain any command line arguments. Instead they belong in the *arg* tags like in the example.